# Prove that $L(S\cap T) \subseteq L(S)\cap L(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am asked to prove

> $L(S\cap T) \subseteq L(S)\cap L(T)$

I am at a complete loss as to where to even start. I understand that they are not equal because for example part of the basis for $S$ could be $e_i$ and for $T$ could be $2e_i$, but how do I prove the above statement? I am not looking for a complete proof but merely a hint to get me started.

Should I maybe write the elements of the two sets as linear combinations of their basis components? Where would I go from there though?

Comment: What is $L$ here?

Comment: @Wuestenfux $L(S)$ is the subspace spanned by $S$.

Comment: So then, what does it mean to be an element of a subspace spanned by whatever ?  @JohnArg

Comment: @GrahamKemp If $x$ is an element of a subspace spanned by $S$, then $x$ can be represented as a linear combination of the elements of $S$.

Comment: Exactly, @JohnArg . So take any element of $L(S\cap T)$ (a linear combination of elements in both $S$ and $T$), and argue that it is an element in both $L(S)$ and $L(T)$ (ie: both a linear combination of elements in $S$, and a linear combination of elements in $T$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $A,B$ be subsets of $V$.
If $A\subseteq B$, then $L(A)\subseteq L(B)$.

In your case, $S\cap T\subseteq S$ and so $L(S\cap T)\subseteq L(S)$. Similarly, $L(S\cap T)\subseteq L(T)$. Therefore, $L(S\cap T)\subseteq L(S)\cap L(T)$.